# `Marshal.StructureToPtr` throws exception trying to get byte array representation of a structure

Tags: c#, exception, marshalling

I'm going to save a `DataTable` to *.dbf file (dBase IV). So I have a structure like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 1)]
public struct DbfHeader
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private byte versionNumber;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    private byte yearOfLastUpdate;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    private byte monthOfLastUpdate;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    private byte dayOfLastUpdate;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private Int32 numberOfRecords;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    private Int16 lengthOfHeader;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    private Int16 lengthOfEachRecord;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    private Int16 reserved1;

    [FieldOffset(14)]
    private byte incompleteTransaction;

    [FieldOffset(15)]
    private byte encryptionFlag;

    [FieldOffset(16)]
    private byte[] freeRecordThread;

    [FieldOffset(20)]
    private byte[] reserved2;

    [FieldOffset(28)]
    private byte mdxFlag;

    [FieldOffset(29)]
    private byte languageDriver;

    [FieldOffset(30)]
    private Int16 reserved3;

    public DbfHeader(int numberOfRecords, int numberOfFields, short recordLength, Encoding encoding)
    {
        // some code that initialize each field
    }

}
```

Also, I have a method to convert `DbfHeader` variables to `byte[]` array like this:

```
public static byte[] StructureToByteArray<T>(T structure)
{
    int len = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, ptr, true);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, result, 0, len);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return result;
}
```

But this method is not working. At the `Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, ptr, true)` line, I get this exception:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Anyone knows what is going wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Although it's a standard practice in C, in C# it's uncommon to copy between byte arrays and structs. Marshalling is intended for invoking unmanaged code, which you aren't doing here. Have a look at the [BinaryWriter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) instead.

Comment: @dtb Yes. That's right. But reading/writing all these fields with BinaryReader/BinaryWriter classes looks to be hard coding. When you have to do it for several number of structures, it will be harder. So I thought writing a single function can solve it for all the structures that I have.

Comment: @dtb Is there any other way to map byte arrays and structs (in C#) using a single function?

Comment: Your structure contains managed object references to byte arrays (`byte[]`). That is, `freeRecordThread` & `reserved2` are *not* an "in-place" byte array, but a *reference* to such a byte array. I wouldn't be surprised if these at least partly cause your problem. If you need e.g. 4 "filler" bytes, either don't declare anything at that `FieldOffset` at all, or declare the fields e.g. as `int` (or `long` in the case of `reserved2`).

Comment: @stakx Thanks. Can you say what is the best way to map these kind of structs to byte[]? I found `BinarySerialization` and `Marshalling`. The first one doesn't match my need as it add additional data to the byte stream. The second one is suited for unmanaged codes. Any other way?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: I don't know. Converting `byte[]` to a `struct` is already very unusual in .NET; converting to a `struct` that in turn "contains" a `byte[]` may be impossible (because arrays are reference types and referenced, not stored in-place). I suggest you omit those fields if you don't need to access them, or declare them as a sequence of separate `byte`/`short`/`int`/`long` fields, and decompose them into a `byte[]` in a second step.

Comment: @stakx your comment solved another problem of mine. I was going to convert back the byte[] to struct and as I used managed object reference I couldn't do that. I redesign and used shor/int/long and every things goes well. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you passing `fDeleteOld` as true to `Marshal.StructureToPtr()`?

You should be passing `false` as far as I can see.

I think you should also be calling Marshal.DestroyStructure() after copying the memory:

```
public static byte[] StructureToByteArray<T>(T structure)
{
    int len = Marshal.SizeOf(structure);
    byte[] result = new byte[len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(len);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, ptr, false);
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, result, 0, len);
    Marshal.DestroyStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    return result;
}
```

The reason it was crashing before was because passing the `fDeleteOld` as true assumes that you have *already* called `Marshal.StructureToPtr()` for that IntPtr. Because you hadn't, it crashed (the memory block was not initialised in the way that StructureToPtr() was expecting).

However, you still need to clean up the memory by calling `Marshal.DestroyStructure()` as per my example above. This is needed to clean up data used for structures that contain references. (Your particular example struct doesn't contain references, but you could pass such a struct to your `StructureToByteArray()`).

Finally, note that if you did this, it wouldn't crash (this code is pointless other than to demonstrate how the `fDeleteOld` flag is used):

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, ptr, false); // First time; must be false.
Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, ptr, true); // Second time: Now it can be true.
```

Comment: It solves the problem! but can you explain why it throws exception when `fDeleteOld` was set to true?

Comment: @MatthewWatson For your last code, is it **can** be true or **must** be true or **should** be true?

Comment: @joe: It can be true or false; it will not cause a crash either way. But if it's passed as `false` then the previous struct memory will not be freed and would represent a memory leak. (This is all described in the documentation for `StructureToPtr()`.)

Comment: Uh...in order to prevent memory leak, which is necessary in a healthy program, it **must** be true then. Thanks!